# Unable to login into registry hosted in swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-registry

I have a 2 node swarm cluster as follows

[image: pic]

On Swarm I have created a `registry` container with basic authentication as follows

```
$ mkdir auth

$ docker run \
  --entrypoint htpasswd \
  registry:2.6.2 -Bbn admin admin > auth/htpasswd

$ docker run -d \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  --restart=always \
  --name registry \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=basic-realm" \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
  registry:2.6.2
```

Now when I try login in the registry I get below error

```
$ docker login registry
Username: admin
Password: admin
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry on 10.0.2.3:53: server misbehaving
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1317#issuecomment-285334588) github link  and updated `nameserver 10.0.2.3:53` in `/etc/resolv.conf` as `nameserver 8.8.8.8` but it didn't fixed the issue

```
$ docker login registry                                                             
Username: admin
Password: admin
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

I also tried to update `/etc/hosts` with `8.8.8.8` but same error

> Note: All commands are run from swarm manager node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mount `/auth` directory, using this flag `-v "$(pwd)"/auth:/auth` while creating container fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you do `docker login registry`, docker is trying to resolve this name on internet, which does not exist.
`registry` is simply your container name. It is not a domain.

The solution here is to use `localhost` instead of `registry` :

```
docker login localhost:5000
```

Comment: Hello @Marc when I tried `docker login localhost:5000` I got this error `Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://localhost:5000/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request`

Comment: Hmm.. what happens if you curl the registry catalog ? `curl http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog`

Comment: If I issue `curl localhost:5000/v2/_catalog` I am getting this message `{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"registry","Class":"","Name":"catalog","Action":"*"}]}]}`